# Cholov Israel microwave

Tags: halacha, kashering-kosherization, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

If someone is careful about only eating dairy which is Cholov Israel, is it OK to use a microwave which has been used for Cholov stam, without doing anything to kasher the microwave or wrapping the food?

Comment: Are they careful because they think Cholov Stam is treif or because of a personal/community chumra/minhag ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details of this kind of question are discussed in the [Shach Y.D. 119 s.q. 20](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4384). The upshot is that no, it is not OK. Only if someone were microwaving food for a group and a person happens to partake, would there be a reason to be lenient (there are still other factors involved, but that is where the heter starts - you can't just use it yourself because others have a more lenient opinion).

The Shach is rather involved, but this is how [Rabbi Yossef Slotnik](http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/287481-kashering-from-chalav-stam-am) explains it.

(NOTE: This presumes that a microwave requires Kashering at all - that is not universally agreed upon, and it presumes that the keeping of Cholov Yisroel isn't just as an extra Chumra. If the latter were the case, there may be further reasons to be lenient in extenuating circumstances).

Answer (score 3):

If it is because of keeping it as a chumra (as do many in the United States) then one can even use the milchik utensils and pots used for Chalav Stam as long as they are clean. This is from the psak of a rav with Yoreh Yoreh semicha who keeps Chalav Yisroel and Bais Yosef shechitah as a chumra but eats in my house with no problem (I do not keep either).

Comment: Is this Rav notable? There are plenty of people with Yoreh Yoreh semicha who I wouldn't really want paskining for me...

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know how "notable" he is but I have used him for psak and was trying to show somehow  that he is worthy of respect without being too explicit and identifying him. Of course he is a close relative so I "may" be prejudiced. The point was to show how someone who keeps it as a chumra would tend to act.

Comment: There is a special dispensation of halacha for close relatives to avoid disputes and to keep Shalom.  I would hardly accept someone who knows the Teshuva of Rav Moshe who eats Cholov Stam as a chumra to paskin Shailos.

Answer (score 1):

According to the OU's website, if you double wrap food for use in a microwave, it can even be cooked in a microwave oven which has cooked non-kosher food.

[OU Kashrut on Microwaves](http://www.ou.org/jewish_action/06/2007/kosher_food_in_a_non_kosher_office/)

Comment: Sorry i was asking about if it has been used for cholov stam even without being wrapped.

Comment: I would ask a Rav, but I can't see a problem with it.

Comment: @jim You should clarify in your question what exactly you are seeking by [editing](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/44515/edit). As always, the clearer you are and the more information you include, the more likely you'll get what you want in an answer. This answer is describing one way you could go about using such a microwave.

Comment: @Jim basically the answer is to only use the Microwave when your items are double wrapped.